# Which is grammatically correct in English? Don't forget to write one, too. or Don't forget to write one, either?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, polarity-items

> A. Let's make a birthday cake for her.
>   B. Good idea. I'll write her a card. Don't forget to write one, too/either.
>   A. I won't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**too** / **either** indicates that one person or things is (to be) treated the same as one that has already been mentioned. **too** is used in positive sentences:

> I have told Jane. - *positive*
>   I have told Mary too. - *positive*

**either** is used in negative sentences, but only if the first sentence is also negative:

> I haven't told Jane. - negative
>   Don't tell Mary either! - negative

If you have a positive sentence followed by a negative sentence, you use **too**, even though the second sentence is negative...

> I have told Jane. - *positive*
>   Don't tell Mary too! - *negative*

Adding **forget to** doesn't really affect the choice of adverb:

> I have told Jane. - *positive*
>   Don't forget to tell Mary too! - *negative*

So, in your sentence, the two parts are:

> I'll write her a card. - *positive*
>   Don't forget to write one, too - *negative*

**too** is the correct adverb to use, even though the second sentence is negative, because the first sentence is positive.

Note that, if both sentences are negative, you use **either**:

> I won't forget to write her a card. - *negative*
>   Don't forget to write one, either - *negative*